# Setting up web address for intranet iis7

Tags: html, iis, iis-7, asp-classic, intranet

I've set up my web address in hosts file so that i can type in a website name instead of location of a file. I now want to expand this so that users over my lan network can access this website as well.

So far users on the network can access my website by typing in the name of the pc followed by the location of the file. How can i enable other users to use this website without typing in `the name of the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask your Network team to create a DNS Alias record that points to your PC name. This assumes that your organization is using Active Directory as your Domain Controller and DNS.